# asp.net + Binding DataSet to already bounded Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

Basically what I want to achieve here is to show more items in batches just like the YouTube comments session in every vid, about 10 comments shows up for the start with a "Show More" button below which loads additional comments in batches of 10 when clicked upon. Anyone has a clue of how to go about this?

Not sure if this is right but what I intend to do now is to bind additional records to my Listview again with DataSets without extracting the data that has already been bonded.

Currently I am binding my first set of records with a Dataset filled with data from my SQL Server like this:

```
 DataSet ds = activityBll.GetActivityAttendees(activityId);
  DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
  uilvEventParticipants.DataSource = dt;
  uilvEventParticipants.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to do as you suggest, and just keep getting more records from farther and farther in the past.  You'll experience increasing delays as you rebind, and if you allow users to make changes to comments you'll have to do a huge postback to process those.  If you go this way you should look at UpdatePanels.

The most elegant would involve jQuery or a similar Ajax technology to fetch additional records and add them to the bottom of an HTML table (not necessarily a ListView) without refreshing the page.  There are quite a few questions on this board about doing that.